# Fix a Windows 8 unsigned driver

Tags: windows-8, boot, drivers

I have installed a legal copy of Windows 8 on an illegal copy of Windows 7.

Now every time I boot, Windows finds some wrong driver and tries to restore system.

I have to boot with "Don't verify the driver signature". How can I find which driver is causing this and replace it manually?

Alternatively, what is best solution without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: The only option I would consider is unlikely a solution you will want to hear.

Comment: noooooooooooooo

Comment: Unless you can get into safe mode your options are limited

Answer (score 1):

Run the `sigverif.exe` utility if you can get in and it'll output system files that aren't signed.  Also, you may need to reregister system files using `regsvr32.exe`.

Comment: This tool showed only the Logtech driver as unsigned. THe uninstalling  didn't helped.